# Extract XML In A MySQL Table Column

Tags: mysql, xml, xml-parsing

I have a table 'Users' with column 'Values' in a MySQL database which has XML data like so:

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="first" value="Linda"/>
    <entry key="groups" value="Manager"/>
    <entry key="last" value="Davis"/>
    <entry key="locked" value="N"/>
    <entry key="status" value="A"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

I wish to extract them like:

```
Attributes_Values
=================
first = Linda
groups = Manager
last = Davis
```

I tried ExtractValue function but it returns null.

```
select ExtractValue(Values, '/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="first"]/entry/value') as Attribute_Values from Users;
```

Not sure if key value pairs can be extracted with a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know the `key` - that's what you are filtering on, so you only need to fetch the corresponding `value`. You can do this with the following xpath expression:

```
/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="first"]/@value
```

You can concatenate the returned value with the key to get the pair:

```
select concat('first = ',ExtractValue(Values, '/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="first"]/@value')) as Attribute_Values
from Users;
```